# For loop conditions in Javascript/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mongodb

I am trying to display the contents of a table and got that working correctly using:

```
<div class="mrb-notification alert alert-success alert-dismissable" ng-repeat="thing in awesomeThings">
<button type="button" class="close" ng-click="hideThing(thing)">&times;          </button>
{{thing.name}} <font color="gray"><p class="text-right">{{thing.date | date : 'medium'}}</p></font>
</div>
```

This displays all the "thing" in "awesomeThings", and the users can click a close button with the function "hideThing(thing), which would add the current user's ID to an array in awesomeThings. This array contains a list of users who chose to hide "thing".

My question now is, how do I go about only displaying "thing" if the current user is not in the array. The user id variable is called "getCurrentUser.id" and the array is called "hideFromUser".

In my head, I am trying to do something like

```
PSEUDOCODE
//for thing in awesomethings
 //show thing if 
  //getCurrentUser.id is not in thing.hideFromUser
```

Is there a way I can do this using ng-if and ng-repeat or do I implement this in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement a js method like isShown(hiddenUserArray) on the $scope and then call this fn with ng-if="isShown(thing.hideFromUSer)".

We would use the lodash lib (e.g. _.contains) to implement the fn.